# Update Concat statement SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do an update to a column by concatenating some new data into the field.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[EmailReporting]
SET [EmailTo] = CONCAT(EmailTo, '; Reporting@xyz.com')
WHERE ReportTypeId in (3, 4, 5, 6)
```

This particular database is 2008 and I guess concat only works in 2012 because I'm getting an error that it is not a recognized function name. What would be the equivalent for 2008?

Comment: u can use `+` operator

Comment: `SET [EmailTo] += ';Reporting@xyz.com'` but it would likely be better to have a design where each address lives on its own row.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed!